# GWT - Client-Side File Uploads

Tags: java, gwt, file-upload

I have been messing around with GWT uploads lately.  I want to have the ability to upload an XML file from the client, and get the contents of that file (display the contents in a TextArea).

From what I have found on the net, it seems I would have to upload the file to the server, and then get the contents of the file.  I do not particularly like the idea of allowing file uploads to the server (even if they are only XML).  Is there anyway to pull the contents of a file that the client specifies without sending it to the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of security restrictions you cannot access the file on the client side alone. It **has** to be sent to the server for processing.

Answer (score 3):

Recent (decent?) browsers implement the "HTML5" [File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) that's quite easy to use in GWT using  JSNI.
See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications